# Details section is not showing in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have inserted existing sub report in details section. But when I ran the report, in preview section details are missing.
please find below screen shots:
Design Section:
[image]
Preview Section:
[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Details are present there still pages along with page 1... check those.

Comment: Thanks for your response :) I am getting headers of the report but not the details.